# How to run Golang tests with specific tag but exluding folder

Tags: go

I want to run integration test across the repo, excluding e2e folder:
Integration tests have the following at the top of each file:

```
//go:build integration
// +build integration
```

```
go test -v -timeout 30s -race -cover -tags integration $(go list ./... | grep -v /e2e)
```

But it doesn't work, it still runs all tests, including unit tests which comes without tags.

Comment: using the `integration` tag will include files that depend on that build tag; it will not exclude others, unless they have a directive such as `// +build !integration`, which would be burdensome to maintain.

Comment: I find it's generally better to use environment variables to control which tests are run.  When the expect env variable is missing, you can call `t.Skip("TEST_FOO not set")` for example.  Then run your tests with:  `TEST_FOO=true go test ./...` to include the FOO suiet.  Or maybe `TEST_E2E=true go test ./...` to run E2E tests.

Comment: @JonathanHall, considering I don't want to run tests 2 times for unit and integration. What might be the best way to do that?

Comment: My normal approach is to hide long-running/integration tests behind an environment variable. For larger projects, there may be multiple flags of this type.  i.e. TEST_DATABASE, TEST_INTEGRATION, TEST_E2E, etc.

Then when I want to run them all, I just enable them all:  `TEST_DATABASE=1 TEST_INTEGRATION=1 TEST_E2E=1 go test ./...`

Comment: An alternative approach (sorry, I know it's not an answer) is to use the `--short` flag, specifically for use in long-running tests or simply tests you don't want to test every time. https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Skipping